# How to make two <button> tags, where one triggers text and removes the other text?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have two `<button>` tags, like this:

`<button id="functionyes" onclick="functionYes()">Yes</button>`

`<button id="functionno" onclick="functionNo()">No</button>`

They link to functions like this:

```
function functionNo() {
    var x = document.getElementById("functionyes");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("functionno").disabled = true;
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("functionno").disabled = false;
    }
}

function functionYes() {
    var x = document.getElementById("functionno");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("functionyes").disabled = true;
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("functionyes").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

These functions toggle a `<div>` like this from visible to invisible:

```
<div style="display:none" id="functionYes">
    Yes
  </div>

<div style="display:none" id="functionNo">
    No
 </div>
```

So what this does is when you click, say the Yes button, it triggers the function, which shows the Yes text. Then, the function disables the No button until you toggle the Yes text back off. It’s the same way vice versa.

While this function works, it is not what I really would like to do. I want to have the button instead of disabling the other, it makes the other’s text disappear. So if the Yes text was showing, you could click the No button, making the Yes text disappear, and the No text shows up.

Comment: I assume your functions are not named the same thing

Comment: I guess you want to hide and show just the divs and not the buttons, right?

Comment: So you want the text of the button to change? So the "No" button won't have any text - it will be a blank button - until you click it, and when you click it the text "Yes" disappears from the first button, and the text "No" appears in the second button. Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @AnsBilal Why? stackoverflow has snipplets, can make it run right here, no need for a third party site.

Comment: Oh wait no sorry. The functions have different names. And I want the `<div>` to disappear not the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify your code, just pass in what you want to show and what you want to hide.

```js
function showHide(show, hide) {
  document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById(hide).style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showHide('yes', 'no')">Yes</button>
<button onclick="showHide('no', 'yes')">No</button>

<div id="yes" style="display:none">Yes</div>
<div id="no" style="display:none">No</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it makes stuff like this very easy to do:

```
<button id="yes">Yes</button>
<button id="no">No</button>

<div id="yes-div">Yes</div>
<div id="no-div">No</div>

<script>
    $('#yes').click( () => {
        $('#yes-div').show();
        $('#no-div').hide();
    });
    $('#no').click( () => {
        $('#no-div').show();
        $('#yes-div').hide();
    });
</script>
```